# custom 500 error page is classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, http-status-code-500

I'v got this in my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.asp" />
         <error statusCode="500" redirect="/500.asp" />
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
          <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="/404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <remove statusCode="500" />
            <error statusCode="500" path="/500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>

      <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <add value="home.asp" />
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The 404 redirect works fine but the 500 redirect does nothing. I'm completely baffled. Little help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following. Note the subStatusCode

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" path="/errorpage500-100.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```